# Is there a way to prevent npm from creating symlinks of workspace packages inside node_modules?

Tags: npm, eslint, eslint-plugin-import

We are working on a monorepo that uses npm workspaces. One of the directories in this project is special in the sense that we don't want to allow packages within this directory to create imports to each other. We are currently using eslint with "eslint-plugin-import" no-restricted-path rule to block packages within this directory from importing from sibling directories.

Starting from some version of npm it started automatically creating symlinks of these packages within node_modules making the restriction useless. I don't want to block all of node_modules and I cannot list all the siblings manually for each added package.

Is there a way to tell npm not to create these symlinks for workspace packages in node_modules?